# With RabbitMQ how can I get a rolling message expiration like AWS SQS SetMessageVisibility, or Azure renew lock?

Tags: rabbitmq, amazon-sqs

I have built a solution using AWS SQS queue, and calling the SetMessageVisibility periodically to keep the message hidden (i.e still processing) in the consumer.  These messages in the queue can take seconds to literally hours and have no way of knowing how long they will take. I have done the same thing in Azure by calling the renew lock.

My question is, as I'm exploring RabbitMQ, how can I do the same thing?  It seems once a message has been delivered to the consumer, the consumer has a configurable [delivery acknowledge timeout](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#acknowledgement-timeout) (default of 30 mins) to manually acknowledge so the message can be discarded.

If the consumer is taking hours to process the message, RabbitMQ will then requeue the message for another consumer.

What I would like is to keep the number low, so if the consumer dies, another consumer can pick up the message.

Is this possible in RabbitMQ? ([this video does](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uY5PYGad8Sc) a great example of what I'm wanting to do)